# How can I give my sprite a maximum x coordinate?

Tags: python, pygame, max

Here is some code that moves a rocketship sprite left and right. at the end is code that I thought would help it not go out of the window, however, it doesn't work. Does anyone maybe know how to fix the issue?

```
import pygame

#Set width and height of window
(width, height) = (400, 600)

#sets rocket starting coordinates
rocketX = 200
rocketY = 450

#Sets the colours
background_colour = (0,2,20)

#creates window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Dodger')

#All images
#rocket
rocket = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
rocket = pygame. transform. rotate(rocket, 90)
rocket = pygame.transform.smoothscale(rocket, (50, 100))

screen.fill(background_colour)

running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #makes cursor invisible
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    #draws new layer over screen
    underlay = pygame.draw.rect(screen, background_colour, (0, 0, 400, 600))

    #tracks the mosue location
    mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #displays the rocket
    screen.blit(rocket, (rocketX,rocketY))

    #sets rocket horizontal position
    if mouseX>550:
        rocketX=550
    else:
        rocketX = mouseX
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object instead of `rocketX` and `rocketY`:

```py
rocket = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
rocket = pygame. transform. rotate(rocket, 90)
rocket = pygame.transform.smoothscale(rocket, (50, 100))
rocket_rect = rocket.get_rect(topleft = (200, 450))
```

Use [`clamp_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) to keep the rectangle in the window:

```py
rocket_rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())
screen.blit(rocket, rocket_rect)
```

Note, you can get and set the rocket's position using `rocket_rect.x` and `rocket_rect.y` instead of `rocketX` and `rocketY`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but the threshold you are using is off of the screen. Change `550` to `width - 50` (in this case 300):

```py
if mouseX > width - 50:
    rocketX = width - 50
else:
    rocketX = mouseX
```